# retrieve firebase storage image and display it in the UI

Tags: android, firebase-storage

I need some guidance on downloading an image from firebase and then displaying it on the UI. I believe from what i can find downloaded the file correctly and firebase notices that it has sent data. I cant for the life of me get it to display though. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
            StorageReference jobRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://********************.appspot.com/bd67a3b962538b24-0.jpg");


            final File localFile = File.createTempFile("jobNumbers","png");

            jobRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    // Local temp file has been created
                    StorageReference temp = taskSnapshot.getStorage();
                    Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(temp.getPath());
                    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                    iv.setImageBitmap(img);



                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    // Handle any errors
                }
            });
```

Comment: Are you getting an error or any indication of what's happening here? I recommend using something like Glide or Picaso to do image loading. You can see an example here: https://gist.github.com/puf/f49a1b07e92952b44f2dc36d9af04e3c#file-chatmessageviewholder-java-L35 from our video at I/O: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE

Comment: Ok thanks, ill give it a shot, and no error but ive ran a get byte size and got the correct size of the image

Comment: It sounds like you're not getting the `ImageView` correctly--can you verify that `iv != null`?

Comment: it was non null, but using the video and some other googling, i have it working now. Had to use Glide. Thanks!